# Is it possible to make Tkinter scrollbars move independently of each other in different Toplevel windows?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Imagine there are two Tkinter.Toplevel() windows, called Window_1 and Window_2, which can be opened by clicking the same button (lets called Button_0).

Button_0 is pressed and Window_1 pops up. In Window_1, I can scroll up and down using a mouse pad (MAC OS). After that, I left Window_1 open.

Button_0 is pressed again and Window_2 pops up, while Window_1 stays open. In Window_2, I can again scroll up and down.

Now, I go back to Window_1 and try to scroll using mouse pad, contents in Window_1 DO NOT MOVE, but contents in Window_2 DO MOVE.

Then I close Window_2, and try to scroll on Window_1, this time I got error messages asking for a canvas on Window_2.

I did bind function,

```
def on_vertical(canvas,event):
     canvas.yview_scroll(-3 * event.delta, 'units')
```

to a canvas inside each windows. As far as I know about the error, it seems that this function could not be used twice at the same time (both windows are opened).

I would like the way that when both Windows stay open. While on each window, I can scroll up-down while the another one do not move. Is it possible to code that?

This is the code example (please do noted that the Window name is not corrected label.)

```
from tkinter import *


######################## FUNCTIONS (DEF) ########################
def on_vertical(canvas,event):
    canvas.yview_scroll(-3 * event.delta, 'units')

######################## FUNCTIONS (CLASS) ########################
class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    #INITIAL WINDOW
    def init_window(self):

        self.master.title("Main Window")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        Button(self, text="Button_0",command = self.load_and_print).place(x = 7, y = 95)

        # creating a button instance
        Button(self, text="EXIT PROGRAM", command=self.client_exit).place(x=500, y=250)


    #OPEN A NEW WINDOW CONTAINING STOCK LISTS
    def load_and_print(self):

        new_window = Toplevel(self)
        new_window.title("Window")

        canvas = Canvas(new_window, width = 800, height = 500, scrollregion = (0, 0, 0, 2500))
        frame = Frame(canvas)

        vbar = Scrollbar(new_window, orient = VERTICAL, command = canvas.yview)
        vbar.pack(side = RIGHT,fill = Y)

        canvas.create_window(0,0, window = frame, anchor = NW)
        canvas.config(yscrollcommand = vbar.set)
        canvas.pack(side = TOP,expand = True,fill = BOTH)
        canvas.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', lambda event, canvas=canvas: on_vertical(canvas,event))

    #MAKE PROGRAM EXIT
    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

######################## MAIN PROGRAMME ########################
#call window
root = Tk()

#size of the window
root.geometry("700x300")

app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
root.update()
```

Comment: Provide an executable example of this for people to help with.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Please provide a [mcve] that shows the incorrect behavior.

Comment: yes, you can. But you have to assing scrollbars to two different elements. It seems you assing both scrollbars to the same element. If you have many elements then you may have to keep them on list, not assign to the same variable. Or create class with self.window and self.scrollbar.

Comment: @BryanOakley please take a look at my code.

Comment: @furas: no, that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `bind_all` instead of `bind` for the mousewheel event.

Because you're using `bind_all`, each time you create a new window it replaces the old binding with a new binding. No matter which window gets the event, your function will always only work for the last window to be created. And, of course, when that window is destroyed then the mouse binding will throw an error since the canvas no longer exists.

### Using bind

One solution is simple: use `bind` instead of `bind_all`.

```
canvas.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', lambda event, canvas=canvas: on_vertical(canvas,event))
```

### Using bind_all

If you want the benefits of `bind_all` -- namely, that the scrolling works even if the mouse is over some other widget, you need to modify `on_vertical` to figure out which canvas to scroll at the time that it is running instead of having the canvas being passed in.

You can do that with a little bit of introspection. For example, the `event` object knows which widget received the event. From that you can figure out which window the mouse is in, and from that you can figure out which canvas to scroll.

For example, move the binding up to the `__init__` and change it like this:

```
self.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', on_vertical)
```

Next, change `on_vertical` to figure out which canvas to scroll. In the following example I assume each toplevel has exactly one canvas and that you always want to scroll that canvas (ie: you lose the ability to scroll text widgets and listboxes)

If that's not the case, you can add whatever logic you want to figure out which widget to scroll.

```
def on_vertical(event):
    top = event.widget.winfo_toplevel()
    for child in top.winfo_children():
        if child.winfo_class() == "Canvas":
            child.yview_scroll(-3 * event.delta, 'units')
            break
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! But not when I placed my mouse over the text (from `Label(...)`), it is not scrollable until I change the binding back to `bind_all`, is there any other way?

Comment: @np2314: I've updated my answer with a second solution.